# How to draw checkbox without 3d frame

Tags: c++, winapi, checkbox, controls, draw

I use the `DrawFrameControl` function to draw a checkbox:

```
DrawFrameControl(hdc, &r, DFC_BUTTON,  DFCS_CHECKED);
```

and this is result:

[image]

But I do not need a 3d frame, I need a simple 1-pixel frame like this:

[image]

if I pass to `DrawFrameControl` function a DFCS_FLAT flag, then I get a bold frame:
[image]

Is there a way to draw a checkbox with a 1-pixel border?

Comment: The visual appearance is a user setting. Honor it, don't fight it. If you *do* need complete control over the appearance (which I strongly discourage), use [custom or owner-drawn controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373487.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Use `DrawThemeBackground` to draw check box in different states.

See also
[Parts and States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773210(v=vs.85).aspx)
[Visual Styles Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773178(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
HTHEME htheme = OpenThemeData(hwnd, L"BUTTON");
if(htheme)
{
    DrawThemeBackground(htheme, hdc, BP_CHECKBOX, CBS_CHECKEDNORMAL, &rc, 0);
    CloseThemeData(htheme);
}
```

Required headings and libraries:

```
<Uxtheme.h>
<vsstyle.h>
"Uxtheme.lib"
```

Comment: How does this answer the question "Is there a way to draw a checkbox with a 1-pixel border?" that the OP stated?

Comment: @DavidRector This method draw a check box with 1-pixel border. This is the only way other than manually drawing a rectangle with `Rectangle` API

Answer (score 1):

I need to draw a checkbox image exactly the same as it looks in the network adapter properties window, for example:

[image]

Why I don't want to use the `DrawThemeBackground` function? First, I need to draw the appearance of the checkbox exactly the same as described above. Secondly, the `DrawThemeBackground` function will only works if the Windows theme is enabled, and the checkbox will look themed.

`DrawFrameControl` function draws the 3d border with the checkbox. This does not fit.
so I decided to write checkbox drawing code using `Rectangle`, `MoveToEx` and `LineTo` functions:

```
HPEN old_pen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(128, 128, 128)));
HBRUSH old_brush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hdc, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255)));

Rectangle(hdc, 0, 0, 11, 11);
DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc, old_pen));
DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc, old_brush));

old_pen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(0, 0, 0)));

MoveToEx(hdc, 1, 4, NULL);
LineTo(hdc, 5, 8);
MoveToEx(hdc, 4, 7, NULL);
LineTo(hdc, 9, 2);

DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc, old_pen));
old_pen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 255, 255)));

MoveToEx(hdc, 1, 3, NULL);
LineTo(hdc, 1, 6);
MoveToEx(hdc, 1, 6, NULL);
LineTo(hdc, 4, 9);
MoveToEx(hdc, 4, 9, NULL);
LineTo(hdc, 9, 4);
MoveToEx(hdc, 9, 4, NULL);
LineTo(hdc, 9, 1);

DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc, old_pen));
```

And I got the desired result:

[image]